# How to Grep Specific URL Directory Level?

Tags: sorting, grep

For example, i have a list:

```
https://google.com/one/
https://google.com/one/two/
https://google.com/oneone/
https://google.com/one/two/three/
```

How to grep just level one directory? so, my list will be like this:

```
https://google.com/one/
https://google.com/oneone/
```

Or just level two endpoint like this:

```
https://google.com/one/two/
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you want two endpoints `grep -E '^[^:]+://[^/]+/([^/]+/){2}$' file.txt` and then just change the number for different levels

Comment: I don't get any output with this command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Awk will be a better tool for this

```
awk -F\/ 'NF==5 && $4 ~ /one/ { print $1"/"$2"/"$3"/"$4 }' file

https://google.com/one/
https://google.com/oneone/

awk -F\/ 'NF==6 && $4 ~ /one/ { print $1"/"$2"/"$3"/"$4 }' file

https://google.com/one/two/
```

Use / as the field separator and check for the number of fields and the that field 4 contains one, printing the result.

Comment: This is worked for me, but, how if i have a line like this `https://google.com/one/two/three/four.json`? I tried with the above command but not working.

Comment: The number of field would be 7 (separated by /) and so you would run the same command but change NF== to NF==7

Comment: If i set to 7, the output is `https://google.com/one/two/three/` and
`https://google.com/one/two/three/four.json`. Any way to get only `https://google.com/one/` or `https://google.com/one/two/` (with `https://google.com/one/two/three/four.json` in the list)?

Comment: OK, I've amended the answer

Comment: It's working. Last question, any way to get any level one directory name? For example, i have `https://google.com/one/two/three/four.json` and `https://google.com/test/two/three/four.json`, now the list must be `https://google.com/one/` and `https://google.com/test/`.

Comment: Change the fields that print in the print statement. $1 represents the first / delimited field and $2 the second etc.